# An elegant way to unpool matrix with numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I will describe the problem with an example. There is a matrix

```
[[1 2]
 [3 4]]
```

I need to resize/unpool it to the next one

```
[[1 1 2 2]
 [1 1 2 2]
 [3 3 4 4]
 [3 3 4 4]]
```

The operation is kind of opposite to max pooling in convnets. I have a brute solution with cycles. I would be very happy to see if there is a sophisticated solution with numpy.
My brute force solution is below.

```
matrix = np.arange(1, 5).reshape(2, 2)
matrix_m, matrix_n = matrix.shape
kernel = np.ones((2, 2), dtype=np.int)
kernel_m, kernel_n = kernel.shape
unpooled_matrix = np.zeros((matrix_m * kernel_m, matrix_n * kernel_n), dtype=np.int)
for i in range(matrix_m):
    pos_i = i * kernel_m
    for j in range(matrix_n):
        pos_j = j * kernel_n
        unpooled_matrix[pos_i: pos_i + kernel_m, pos_j: pos_j + kernel_n] = kernel * matrix[i][j]

print(matrix)
print(kernel)
print(unpooled_matrix)
```